# android - How Do I Replace A Scene in Cocos2D

Tags: android, cocos2d, ccsprite

I am using Cocos2D for Android:
I have two scenes `MainScene` and `LogoScene`. I want to show a Splash screen on `LogoScene` then, I want to go to `MainScene`.

I am wondering how I can go from `LogoScene` to `MainScene` using:

```
CCDirector.sharedDirector().replaceScene(MainScene.scene());
```

What is an example of Scene Transition from a splash screen to the main scene?

Comment: So... you just want the same replacement except with a transition?

Comment: Well I want to have a splash screen then, change to MainScene.

Answer (score 0):

The splash screen can just be another scene and you can transition between them using scene transition effects.
Just change the code to match this

```
Director::getInstance()->replaceScene(TransitionFade::create(0.5, mainMenuScreen, Color3B(0,255,255)));
```

This creates a fade effect between your screens. Hope it gives you the desired effect.